# Centre of mass of solid hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass

I am trying to find the centre of mass of a solid hemisphere using theta as a variable. But I am getting the wrong answer. Can you please tell me where I am wrong. My working is shown in the image attached....[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RdƟ is not the thickness of the disk.  It is an arc segment which is not perpendicular to the disk.  You need R cos Ɵ dƟ.  (As Ɵ increases, the angle between the arc and the y direction also increases.)

Comment: Sir,if you are correct at what you are tryin to explain,then the above is the same way in which we derive hollow hemisphere where rd(theta) is assumed as a height and then theta is integrated from 0 to 90 and we get (0,R/2,0) as the result.How?

Comment: @PATRICK Because area can be calculated by taking Rd$\theta$ as the thickness of strip, but the volume of the disc can't be done that way as we were not taking cylindrical hoops in case of hollow hemisphere but here we are taking cylindrical discs.

Comment: I didn't quit get you sir,can you please ellaborate

Answer (score 0):

The thickness of the thin disc cannot be $ R \ d \theta $. Otherwise a disc at $ \theta = 0 $ would be counted as having the same thickness as a disc (sweeping the same angle $ d\theta $) at angle $ \theta = \pi / 2 $, when clearly the disc is thicker at $ \theta = 0 $. So your expression for $ dm $ is missing a factor. I suggest drawing a bigger diagram with a bigger $ d \theta $.

Comment: I did not understand why the thickness would be different at 0 and π/2... Moreover, how would drawing a bigger diagram help???

Comment: @HSB Drawing a bigger diagram, especially making $ d\theta $ bigger, will help visualise the issue with the disc thickness. The important bit is the intersection of the angle with the sphere as seen on your current diagram.

The disc at $ 0 $ is thicker than that at $ \pi / 2 $ assuming they are both swept by the same $ d \theta $. Since you are integrating over $ \theta $ you have to account for that. Essentially you're missing a factor of $ \cos \theta $.

Comment: No sir,thickness will not be same everywhere,because the thickness is a function of theta,and as theta changes thickness changes as well