# Why we consider varying height of element in calculating COM of solid hemisphere but not for hollow hemisphere?

Tags: integration, elements

[image: pic 1] This is how we calculate COM(centre of mass) of hollow hemisphere. We take dA=2piR²cos(theta)d(theta). But while calculating COM for solid hemisphere using this method[image: pic2] if taken dV= piR³cos²(theta)d(theta), I didn't found correct answer. Searching my answer, I found that in case of volume we have to take Rcos(theta)d(theta) in place of Rd(theta) because height of element is varying. But why so? In hollow hemisphere why we don't consider the varying height of element during integration and in solid we do?

[Centre of mass of solid hemisphere](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/500677/342260) here I found that I have to take cos(theta) in extra for solid hemisphere but didn't understood the reason why we don't consider this for hollow one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'varying height' R d(theta) in the case of a thin shell, is the  width of the ring element, to be multiplied by circumference  (2* pi * R * cos(theta)) and by
the thickness of the shell (a constant) to  make
a volume.

The height of
the solid disk-like element of the solid hemisphere
is not the slant height of its edge (R d(theta)) but
rather the perpendicular-to-the-face height
R cos(theta) d(theta), which is then multiplied
by the area of the disk face  pi * (R cos(theta))^2
to give a volume.

R * d(theta) is a strip width, one of the
three volume-determining dimensions of the thin shell ring element, while R * cos(theta) d(theta) is the thickness
dimension of the solid  hemisphere disk element.

Comment: I think i got the answer, in hollow one, we calculate area of element and it does not require height, it requires width but in case of solid one, we calculate volume, it requires height not width (although both mean same but I can feel difference in these two words here) as we are taking disk type element.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is quite confusing. Let's sort something out about integration.

Using spherical coordinates, the elementary volume reads $dV = r^2 \cos \theta dr d\theta d\phi$, while the mass of the elementary volume reads $dm = \rho dV$. For a solid hemisphere, you need to integrate these quantities with $r$ from $0$ to the radius $R$ of the hemisphere, $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$, and $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$

In the example of the hollow hemisphere, you're collapsing the radial dimension to a infinitely thin surface, whose elementary surface element reads $dS = r^2 \cos \theta  d\theta d\phi$, so that the elementary volume reads $dV = dS \, dr$. The elementary mass becomes $dm = \rho dV = \rho dr dS = \sigma dS$, being $\sigma$ the  mass density per unit surface. For a hollow hemisphere, you set $r=R$ and integrate $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$, and $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.